# How is task register updated in xv6 on x86 platform?

Tags: x86, xv6, gdt

In the xv6 source code for x86 architecture, in the `switchuvm` function, the TSS is being updated (as well as the page table but that's not my concern here).  I've been struggling with the concept of the GDT and TSS and so I want to attempt to lay out what I *think* is happening in this function.

```
switchuvm(struct proc *p)
{
  ...
  mycpu()->gdt[SEG_TSS] = SEG16(STS_T32A, &mycpu()->ts,
                                sizeof(mycpu()->ts)-1, 0);   // 1
  mycpu()->gdt[SEG_TSS].s = 0;                               // 2
  mycpu()->ts.ss0 = SEG_KDATA << 3;                          // 3
  mycpu()->ts.esp0 = (uint)p->kstack + KSTACKSIZE;           // 4
  ...
  mycpu()->ts.iomb = (ushort) 0xFFFF;
  ltr(SEG_TSS << 3);                                         // 5
  ...
}
```

In line 1, I believe we are setting the **segment descriptor** in the GDT (which is shared by all cores on a multiprocessing CPU) to point to the new process's **TSS**.  Then, in line 5, the LTR instruction is passed an index into the GDT which points to the TSS segment descriptor.  The core then loads the base address and limit into the **Task Register** so that the core will be able to find the TSS during subsequent interrupts.  This *only works* because these calls are wrapped by a spinlock in the `scheduler` function which is the only function that calls `switchuvm`

So while the Global Descriptor Table is:

-Shared by all the cores of the CPU (by virtue of being in the shared kernel Virtual Address Space)

-The first 4 segment descriptors are never changed because paging is used and so all the kernel threads share the same virtual address space (and these are used for user/kernel code/data) and all user threads have the same illusion of a VAS

-The 5th segment of the GDT is in fact changed during **every context switch** in order to update TR's (which are individual to each core).  The reason this works is because the **atomicity** surrounding updating the GDT (which is in shared kernel VAS) *and* loading the updated entry into the TR

Is this a correct understanding?

Also, what is line 4 doing?  I've thought the kernel stack pointer (i.e. esp) was stored in the context pointer in each proc structure, so I'm confused by what esp0 is referring to.

Comment: " the GDT (which is shared by all cores on a multiprocessing CPU)": I don't think so.   The global `cpus` variable has one element per CPU (i.e. one per core), and `mycpu()` returns the pointer to the one for this CPU.  So the GDT here is being constructed in memory that is effectively private to this core; no other core should have reason to touch it, and thus we in fact have a separate GDT per core.

Comment: It couldn't really work any other way.  If the gdt was shared by all cores, then very core would be trying to set the `SEG_TSS` entry in the gdt to the tss for the particular process that the core was trying to run.  Even if there is a lock around `switchuvm`, so that two cores couldn't *modify* that entry simultaneously, there would remain the problem that core A wants to keep *using* that TSS, but core B could replace it by something else.

Comment: As to "effectively private" above: yes, the gdt is in virtual memory that all the cores see, but each one is going to use a different chunk.  One core could modify another core's GDT if it felt like it, but that would be a kernel bug.  Just like within any program: any function is physically permitted to read and write the entire stack, but if it tries to write outside the part that the programmer wants it to, then that's a bug.

Comment: "Also, what is line 4 doing? I've thought the kernel stack pointer (i.e. esp) was stored in the context pointer in each proc structure, so I'm confused by what esp0 is referring to.": It *is* stored there, for the use of the kernel software, but the only way for the *hardware* to know what stack to switch to is if the stack pointer is actually in the TSS.  So line 4 copies the one to the other.